# Magento 2.1 EE upgrade issues

Tags: magento2, php, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my magento 2.1 EE to latest version 2.3.1 EE. 
But I am getting two issues- 
1. PHP memory limit issues. 
It shows current limit is 512 M and needs to be 756 M or more. 
But after checking on server, memory_limit is 2048 M.

2. Component dependency issues. [image]

Comment: Have you restarted your server after increasing the memory limit

Comment: I have not changed memory limit of server. It is already set 2048M for all PHP version. 
But still I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Update below in your php.ini file:

memory_limit = 1G

NOTE: check memory using phpinfo() function.

You can try with this, Check all php.ini files for memory limit and update them :

php.ini files locations:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Check if you are using php fpm

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

2) For component dependency issues, Please refer below magento 2 devdocs:

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html

Comment: In phpinfo() , it shows memory limit for local as 768 M and 2048 M for Master.

Comment: find 'memmory' in your htaccess file.

Comment: In htaccess also,value is memory_limit 2048M

Comment: are you using apache and nginx?

Comment: I am using apache.

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: Current magento version is 2.1.8 Enterprise Edition and working to upgrade to 2.3.1 EE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93664/discussion-between-saphal-jha-and-chanchal).